# Any system with $\rm SO(3)$ but not $\rm O(3)$ symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, group-theory, parity

If we have a spherical symmetry potential, the single-particle Hamiltonian has not just $SO(3)$ symmetry but even $O(3)$ symmetry. That is, besides being rotationally invariant, it is automatically inversionally invariant.

The natural question is, is there any system rotationally invariant, but not inversionally invariant?

Comment: The property you're asking for has a name - it's called 'chirality'. (hopefully the search word can help you find interesting examples.)

Comment: Take any Lagrangian which has a term with an odd number of epsilon tensors $\varepsilon_{ijk}$.

Answer (score 9):

Simple example with three particles: Lagrangian with interaction term $\det(\vec{x}_1 \vec{x}_2 \vec{x}_3)$.

Comment: Cool answer! Just for curiosity, are you aware of any system that can be somehow modelled with this kind of interaction?

Comment: Good question! I'll think about it.

Comment: But is this interaction realized in some physical system? A realistic one would be more interesting.

Comment: If you ask for an $SO(3)$-symmetric but parity-violating system actually  realized in nature, the weak interactions  (included in the standard-model Lagrangian) obviously have this property. But this interaction cannot be formulated in terms of a simple potential model but requires a relativistic quantum field theory.

Comment: For a parity violating interaction in the nonrelativistic limit consider the exchange of a virtual $Z^0$  between a nucleus and a (nonrelativistic) electron: $V_{pv} =\frac{1}{2} Q_W g_{Z^0}^2 \frac{e^{-M_{Z^0} c r/\hbar}}{r} \vec{\sigma_e} \cdot\vec{v}_e/c +h.c.$ (see M.-A. Bouchiat and C. Bouchiat, Rep. Progr, Phys. 60 (1997) 1351), where $\vec{\sigma}_e$ refers to the spin of the electron and $\vec{v}_e$ is its velocity. The scalar product of an axial-vector and a polar vector is clearly parity-violating. $V_{pv}$ gives a (tiny) correction to the Coulomb potential $V_C = Ze^2/r$.